# Acer extensa 5630 becomes slow and function key does not working well when connected to a projector

Tags: monitor, presentation, projector

I connect my UBUNTU 12.04.1 on acer extensa 5630 to a Sony projector for presentation, but the system become slow and function key does not working well, when i pree it my laptop monitor goes off and projector screen works, after sometime my desktop with mouse pointer are all on projector screen but Laptop monitor displays the presentation. Please give me an idea to rectify it.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problems in the past with my Toshiba P775 running UBUNTU 12.04

1) I find that on most projectors, if I have a VGA cable, all I have to do is go to display and make sure the settings are on mirror. However on the Epson projectors nothing will work other than switching to an HDMI cable. At least no one in my office has figured out a better workaround.

2) Your second problem [presentation  appearing on laptop but
   not on the projector screen] is likely due to the fact that you have automatically been
   booted into extended desktop mode ( Extended desktop allows you to display the 
   presentation while reading notes on your laptop screen) This can actually be pretty
   useful. Simply drag your stuff to the far side of the screen (usually the right) and  it will appear on the projector screen.

Good luck and if anyone has any other advice please post. This problem is a real headache.